# python 3.X windows multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read many topics about differences between window and linux multiprocessing, but still I cannot find the answer.
I have script like:

```
def create_file():
    #here user define output file name
def READ_MANY_LOG():
    #here user define path to log files and we read all these logs to one list()
def  select_unic_value(READ_MANY_LOG):
    #here specified unic value selected
def SEARCH_ENGINE(search_criteria, READ_MANY_LOG):
    #here perform search from all logs with search_criteria and stored to multiprocess dict (return_dict)
def sort_all_logs_per_unic_value(create_file, select_unic_value):
    mpc = 0
    mpa = []
    for n in select_unic_value:
        search_criteria = criteria(n)
        mps = Process(target=SEARCH_ENGINE, args=(search_criteria, READ_MANY_LOG))
        mpa.append(mps)
        mpc = mpc + 1
        if mpc>=multiprocess.cpu_count():
            for p in mpa:
                p.start()
            for p in mpa:
                p.join()
            For t_g in return_dict.values():
                for t_x in t_g:
                    print(t_x,file=out, flush=True, end='')
            print('PRINT done')
            mpc = 0
            mpa = []            
            return_dict = multiprocess.Manager().dict()
create_file()
READ_MANY_LOG()
select_unic_value(READ_MANY_LOG)
if __name__ == "__main__":
MULT.freeze_support()
SORT_BY_MAC_DIR(output_name)
```

It works perfect on linux, because multiprocess inherit values from  `create_file()`
, `READ_MANY_LOG()`, 
`select_unic_value(READ_MANY_LOG)` and start multiprocess only for `SEARCH_ENGINE`.
But on windows because of spawn it starts the whole script in different process. Is there any way for windows to start  multiprocess only for specific part : `SEARCH_ENGINE` ?
thanks  a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In both linux and windows, multiprocess spawns a new process. This is mostly useful where your script needs dedicated access to the cpu, or core - otherwise known as being cpu bound. As a quick aside, your application looks like it's disk bound - as such you may be better off using threads.

In your scripts scenario you need a way for the parent processes to collate or share values amongst all processes. This includes the calling process and all subprocesses launched.

Collation can be done using process pooling. For example, create an array of logs for your processes to work on. Then join the results at the end.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def SEARCH_ENGINE((sc, logs)):
    # Do something with sc and logs
    return myvalue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)

    # results will be a list of return values for each tuple listed
    results = p.map(, [("First Search", "file1"), ("Second Search, ...)])
```

Alternatively, you can use shared memory using `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array`, however this gets a little more complicated as you need to use `ctypes`.